# LightMap Not working properly

Tags: texturing, uv, light

I've made a chips bag model for my game:

[image]

And I textured it like this:

[image]

And I googled on how to make lightmaps and all of them say "Smart UV project" but when I do that, texture on my model gets broken, so that's why I don't want to use smart UV project

Is there another way? There has to be.

Comment: You could add an second UVmap to your object, so you can chenge/edit the layout without affecting texture UV data. Could you be more precise on what is not working properly?

Comment: oh sorry, the thing not working properly is, before posting this question i exactly did what you said, but it looks worse.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot depicting the problem, a description of what you would like to get, what is the workflow you are following and where it fails?

Comment: ok i got it fixed i had overlapping uvs